# Texture painting straight lines

Tags: texture-painting

I'm making a t-shirt design in Blender texture painting. I'm planning on making a design with lines going down straight. Is there any way to do this in texture painting?

Something like this below:
[image]

Comment: Top menu > Stroke > Stroke Method > Line? You'll also need to change the brush falloff in order to have a sharp brush. Also, how does your unwrap look like?

Comment: Thank you, this really did work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top menu > *Stroke > Stroke Method > Line*. When you paint, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> in order to have a vertical or horizontal line:

[image]

Also, if you want a sharp line, change the falloff:

[image]